# How to get work items associated within a pull request using Azure DevOps API

Tags: git, azure-devops, pull-request, azure-devops-rest-api

I try to get Pull Requests using Azure DevOps API. And I want to include associated work items or only work item ids.

I can get PRs using this URL. But the answer does not include any info about work items.

`GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pullrequests?api-version=7.1-preview.1`

The other URL that you can see below that I can get work items per PR using it.

`GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pullRequests/{pullRequestId}/workitems?api-version=7.1-preview.1`

But the count of list of PRs can be big. So I think it is not appropriate to call the second URL each one of them.

Is there any better way to get work items with PR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to get for **one** specific pull request and its associated work items, you can use rest api [Pull Requests - Get Pull Request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-requests/get-pull-request?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) with `includeWorkItemRefs=true`:
[image]

If you would like to get **all** pull requests and associated work items, you have to do with 2 steps:

1. Get the pull requests **id** via rest api [Pull Requests - Get Pull Requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-requests/get-pull-requests?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP).
2. Then with a loop for each pull request, call [Pull Request Work Items - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-request-work-items/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) or above Pull Requests - Get Pull Request rest api to get the associated work items.
   PS script sample:

```
# Define your organization, project, repository, and PAT
$organization = "your-organization"
$project = "your-project"
$repository = "your-repository"
$PAT = "your-PAT"

# Create the base64 encoded authorization header
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "",$PAT)))

# Define the API URL for pull requests
$apiUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/git/repositories/$repository/pullrequests?api-version=6.0"

# Call the API to get all pull requests
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

# Loop through each pull request
foreach($pullRequest in $response.value) {
    # Get the pull request ID
    $pullRequestId = $pullRequest.pullRequestId

    # Define the API URL for work items associated with the pull request
    $workItemsApiUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/git/repositories/$repository/pullrequests/$pullRequestId/workitems?api-version=6.0"

    # Call the API to get associated work items
    $workItemsResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $workItemsApiUrl -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

    # Print the pull request ID and associated work item IDs
    Write-Host "Pull Request ID: $pullRequestId"
    Write-Host "Associated Work Items:"
    foreach($workItem in $workItemsResponse.value) {
        Write-Host $workItem.id
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @wade zhou - MSFT. I need to get multiple pull requests. So I must to use second way with 2 steps. I get that there is no other way. :)